# Changing limits of $\int_0 ^a\int_0 ^b\int_0 ^a\int_0 ^b \sin(x)\sin(\bar{x})\sin(y)\sin(\bar{y})f(x,\bar{x},y,\bar{y})\ dx\ dy\ d\bar{x}\ d\bar{y}$

Tags: integration

I have an integral:
$$\int_0 ^a\int_0 ^b\int_0 ^a\int_0 ^b \sin(x)\sin(\bar{x})\sin(y)\sin(\bar{y})f(x,\bar{x},y,\bar{y}) \, dx \, dy \, d\bar{x} \, d\bar{y}$$ 
Where:
$$f= \dfrac{\sin(\sqrt{(x-\bar{x})^2+(y-\bar{y})^2})}{(x-\bar{x})^2+(y-\bar{y})^2}$$

Under the transformation $\bar{x}=x+u$ and $\bar{y}=y+v$ $\Rightarrow$ $f$ becomes $f(u,v)$
but the limits of integration with respect to $u$ and $v$ change.

Considering only the $x$ part:
$$\int_{-x} ^{a-x}\int_0 ^a \sin(x)\sin(x+u)f(u,v) \, dx \, du$$
Integrating this with respect to $u$ analytically is difficult while with respect to $x$ is easier. But the $u$ limit have $x$ terms. Can I, by any way, make the limits of $u$ as $0$ to $a$ but yet carry a simpler integration with respect to $x$?

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: question: can I by anyway, make the limits of $u$ as $0$ to $a$ but yet carry a simpler integration with respect to $x$? (changing the limits of $x$ would cause no harm)